# MathJax problems in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I'm not sure if this has been reported elsewhere. See for example Fred Kline's comment on quid's answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104608/need-help-defining-placeholders-for-primes

The source is:

```
I expect I will go with $p^{*}$ and if I need to square it, I could do: $(p^{*})^2$.  I think I'll accept this answer.
```

It is of course caused by the pair of *'s in consecutive pieces of maths. Trying the old trick (as a moderator I can edit comments, mwahaha) of backticks just causes the math to display literally in a fixed width font.

Comment: $p^{ * }$ test $(p^{ *})^2$

Comment: It's a problem with the markdown parser, it replaces the '*s' with '<i>' tags. I'm looking into it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed in build rev 2013.7.2.799. From this build on special characters between $ signs won't need to be escaped in comments.

However I should note that this breaks some existing comments that escaped special characters:

```
 $p^{\*}$ test $(p^{\*})^2$
```

The above markup in existing comments renders the same as in posts: $p^{\*}$ test $(p^{\*})^2$, and can be rewritten as `$p^{*}$ test $(p^{*})^2$`

Answer (score 5):

Interesting, I've never come across this problem on Physics.SE (and I just confirmed, it does exist). Maybe because I don't use the asterisk for anything (`\bar` for complex conjugate for me)

Fortunately, there's a workaround, simply pad the asterisk on both sides with a space. LaTeX usually is OK with extra spaces in the mix.

`$p^{ * }$ test $(p^{ *}))^2$`

The same problem does not occur with underscores (`$p_{1}$ test $p_{2}$`), so this is probably something fixable.

Comment: A more versatile workaround is to use `\ast`.